# How do I configure home office routers with GSM backup connection?

Tags: networking, router

I have an ISP provided router on my network (all one subnet), with weak/spotty internet connectivity. It is the DHCP server and handles all DNS lookups etc. (I guess). I have another wired/wifi router with a sim card that I would like to use as an alternate route to the internet, but I'm not sure how to set up either router to ensure both connections are available and the fastest/best is chosen.

The DSL router is a FritzBOX and the secondary GSM router is a TP Link.

I suppose there are custom DNS/Gateway settings required, but it is not clear how they can do what I need them to do.

Comment: If you suspect the DNS provider is to blame use a DNS provider

Comment: This is a multi-WAN situation. A run-off-the-mill SOHO router isn't going to cut it.

Comment: You'll need a router/firewall that is separate from the two modems that manages the internal routing incl. DHCP & makes decisions about which WAN connection to use. Either SW or HW .   e.g. pFsense.  But, will introduce a lot of complexity as dual WAN & routing is non-trivial & you sound inexperienced.  There are dual wan appliances/routers that are simpler to manage but because of the inherent complexity you will likely waste more time trying to do this than waiting for your connection to fix itself.  First you determine technically what is actually going on during these "outages."

Comment: Knowing what is specifically going on is challenging for the average user, but much less so than what you might be thinking of taking on.

Comment: The outages according to the ISP are in the copper lines back to the service cabinet in our street. So far they have no ETA on repair.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, perhaps I was lucky. I have a TP Link Archer MR400 router with the sim card port. The router offers two modes:

1. Run directly off the sim card
2. Run through the WAN port with the sim only connecting as backup with the WAN port was disconnected.

The solution was to run the home off the TP Link router, making it the base DHCP server of the correct base address and range. The DSL router then took an alternate subnet address and was connected in to the WAN port of the TP Link. The machines on the network are not aware of the DSL router now, so there is no need for the dual gateway etc.

One annoyance is the DSL connection while extremely slow, still presents a connection, so I have to force the failover to make the TP Link prefer the GSM connection. Any ideas on how to make the selection automatic would be welcomed.